# MultipleActiveResultSets enabled but not working

Tags: c#, sql

I enabled MARS and still cant execute two SqlDataReaders in one connection,i searched for a solution to enable MARS by default using RegEdit by couldnt find any solution and still getting that error : There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Here is the code :

```
public partial class student_Courses : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string connectionString = "";
    string query1 = "";
    string query2 = "";
    string courseName = "";
    string chapterName = "";
    string chapterVideoName = "";
    string courseValue = "";
    SqlDataReader sr2 = null;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        query1 = "SELECT * FROM Courses";
        query2 = "SELECT * FROM Chapters WHERE value='" + courseValue + "'";
        connectionString = "Data Source=Prince-PC;" + 
                            "Initial Catalog=Elearning;" + 
                            "Integrated Security=True;"+ 
                            "MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
        SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader sr1 = command1.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sr1.Read())
            {
                courseName = sr1["name"].ToString();
                courseValue = sr1["value"].ToString();
                sr2 = command2.ExecuteReader();
                while (sr2.Read())
                {
                    chapterName = TextBox3.Text =  sr2["name"].ToString();
                    chapterVideoName = Label2.Text =  sr2["video_name"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to dispose of `sr2` via a `using` statement as done in [this MSDN MARS example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1a7f4f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```cs
// The following line of code requires
// a MARS-enabled connection.
productReader = productCmd.ExecuteReader();
using (productReader)
{
  while (productReader.Read())
  {
    Console.WriteLine("  " +
      productReader["Name"].ToString());
  }
}
```